# How to add an animation/effect for changing a HTML's content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on fading in the new content of #myform's HTML after the mail has been sent, but I cannot figure out, how to give it an animation, so it doesn't just throw out the new HTML. I'm thinking about something like this with the "fadeIn", but it doesn't work, what's the correct way of doing it?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(function() {
   var newHTML = '<div class="col-sm-12 text-center" style="color:white; background-color:#6f8595; padding-bottom:15px; border-radius:5px; transition:1s;"><h3>Thank you for your message!<br />We will get back to you as soon as possible!</h3></div>';
      
   $('#myform').validate();
   $('#myform').on("submit",function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     if ($(this).valid()) {
       var data = $(this).serialize();
       $(this).html(newHTML).fadeIn("fast");
       $.post( "includes/sendmail.php", {data});
     }
   }); 
 });
 
});
```

Comment: In your jsfiddle you forgot the HTML code, also JQuery is not included

Comment: I didn't include them on purpose, the only think I'd like to achieve is something like  `html(newHTML).fadeIn("fast");` but of course the working version. Do you think they'd be necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first hide the content of the node you just replaced for fadeIn to work properly:

```js
$(function() {
  var newHTML = '<div class="col-sm-12 text-center" style="color:white; background-color:#6f8595; padding-bottom:15px; border-radius:5px; transition:1s;"><h3>Thank you for your message!<br />We will get back to you as soon as possible!</h3></div>';

  $('#myform').validate();
  $("#myform").on("submit", function(e) {
    if ($(this).valid()) {
      console.log("it's valid");
      var data = $(this).serialize();
      $(this).html(newHTML).hide().fadeIn();
      $.post("includes/sendmail.php", {
        data
      });
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form method="POST" id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Nice and simple, works perfectly. Thanks a lot, lesson learnt!

Comment: You're welcome. PS: It would have been better if your question had a runnable snippet inside it

Comment: Thought it's enough this much talking about a small detail, but I'll include the rest in the followings.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   var newHTML = '<div class="col-sm-12 text-center" style="color:white; background-color:#6f8595; padding-bottom:15px; border-radius:5px; transition:1s;"><h3>Thank you for your message!<br />We will get back to you as soon as possible!</h3></div>';
      
  
  $('#myform').on("submit",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

        $(this).fadeOut(3000, function(){
            $('#myform').html(newHTML);
            $('#myform').fadeIn(3000);
        });

}); 
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myform">
  <input id="text" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

On `form` `submit` you can first `fadeOut` the original contents and then you can replace its contents with the newer `html` like following way:

```
$('#myform').on("submit",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        var data = $(this).serialize();

        $(this).fadeOut(3000, function(){
            $('#myform').html(newHTML);
            $('#myform').fadeIn(3000);
        });

        $.post( "includes/sendmail.php", {data});
    }
});
```

You can take an idea from above code but there are N number of combinations that you can do with `fadeIn/fadeOut`. So please fine tune it as per you need.

Comment: It seems to be logic, but when it comes to apply it fades the old one and doesn't fade in the new.

Comment: Now can you please try once more with this new code.

Comment: Still only fades out. `$(this).html(newHTML).hide().fadeIn();` is the simplest solution I guess :)

Comment: Hello. I have added the working snippet. Please have a look at that. I totally agree with you that the accepted solution is quite simpler than this...`:)`!

Comment: Yeah, your snippet works well. You are right, there is many combinations out there, but the more simple the less things go wrong :)